# Polygon Detection from a Set of Lines

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm doing my on implementation of an algorithm called Polygon Detection from a Set of Lines
been reading this [paper](http://web.ist.utl.pt/alfredo.ferreira/publications/12EPCG-PolygonDetection.pdf)

but I'm lost and don't understand what the authors are trying to say on the line 5 of the function "minimum cycle basis"

To be clear, I don't understand how to operate the intersection between 2 numbers and why they check equality between a number and  a vertex
Any help ?

Paper:
[image]

my code:
[image]

Edit:  after i wrote this, i saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363323/minimal-cyle-basis-extracted-from-straight-skeleton?rq=1)
he asked my same question 8 years ago, but no one answer the question

> What the originator means with that condition checking at line 5 and 6 if Π_x,v ∩ Π_v,y = {v} then C ← Π x,v ∪ Π v,y ∪ (x, y), AFAIU from the given pseudo code snippet the content structure of Π must be 2D array which holds the shortest distance for the given distance , e..g Π[2,7] = length_of_vertices(2,7). So what is the sense of having the abscissa and vertex in Π_x,v, what does it really represent?

Comment: x, y, v denote vertex indices (or labels). (x, y) is the edge from vertex x to vertex y. Π denotes a set of vertices and the intersection of the sets must be a singleton {v}.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my interpretation of it:

- (x,y) is a tuple of the two vertices comprising the edge (its start and end points).
- Π is a map whose keys are vertex tuples and values are ordered lists of vertices making up the shortest path between the vertex tuple.
- Π(x,v) is the shortest path from x to v (the result is an ordered list of vertices).
- Π(v,y) is the shortest path from v to y.
- Π(x,v) ∩ Π(v,y) is the *set intersection* between these two shortest paths (which are now treated as sets. rather than ordered lists); if the only vertex the paths have in common is v, then proceed with step 6.